# Windows no longer boots on dual-boot system

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, dual-boot

While trying to delete an Ubuntu partition from my hdd I accidentally rebooted my computer. (Note: the partition was originally made from an existing partition using paragon.)

After that when I tried to start the computer I got the GRUB rescue terminal prompt. I wasn't able to do much from that, but I did manage to boot Ubuntu from a USB drive and to run `boot-repair`.

But now when I try to select Windows 7 from the boot selection menu I get the error `0xc0000225`.

Here is the link to the BootInfo summary created by `boot-repair`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1032584/

I have a lot of very important data on my hdd and I would really appreciate your help.

**The problem was solved with `CHKDSK` from the Windows 7 recovery CD.**

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Are you able to boot into the windows safe mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the windows 7 CD, you need to boot from it, and choose ***Startup Repair*** .

[image]

If you don't have your Windows 7 Cd, you can download a Windows 7 Recovery Disc, you can download it.  Click the desired architecture:

[32-bit (x86)](http://freakshare.com/files/o2db6v0s/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_32-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html)

[64-bit (x64)](http://freakshare.com/files/56apzmkl/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_64-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html)

Comment: I don't have the cd and i was hoping that i can do something from the live usb. I can't download the windws cd because on my usb i have only 4 gb ( and 1 is taken by the linux). Do you know how i can use my hdd for the download?

Comment: Can you use a friend's machine to do that?

Comment: I can, but I was hoping I could use my hdd to download on but I'm not sure how. It wold be easier for me and faster.

Comment: Well, when you go to the site and download the right file, just save it to your hard drive, and then you have to burn it on CD.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do but it seems that i can't see my hard drive from the live usb.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when you rebooted during the middle of a partition operation ... always a ***very*** dangerous thing to do ... you corrupted the partition table in your Master Boot Record (MBR).

The BootInfo summary which was created when you ran `boot-repair` shows the output below from `fdisk` starting around line 478 of [**your pastebin**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1032584/).

```
omitting empty partition (5)

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xab0f55ce

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       105064448  1195399743   545167648    0  Empty
/dev/sda4      1195399761  1250259583    27429911+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5      1195399763  1250259583    27429910+  83  Linux
```

While I am not sure what is the precise meaning of the message `omitting empty partition (5)`, [**this answer on SuperUser**](https://superuser.com/a/321448/37844) which in turn links to [**this post**](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1078820.html) in the Ubuntu forums  where it is claimed that

> - *Any time fdisk reports "omitting empty partition (X)", unfortunately that is a 
>     sure sign that your partition table is corrupt ...*

Notice that `sda3` has a *partition type* (`Id`) of `0` or `Empty`. Since `sda3` is your Windows 7 NTFS partition, the `Id` should be `7` or `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT` the same as it is for `sda1`.

This may be why you can not boot Windows 7. I think the Windows boot process still relies on the values in the MBR partition table being "correct". I think it just gives up if things don't "look right".

I am not sure what to suggest. The obvious first thing would be to create whatever type of a backup you can before you risk doing something that may increase your drive's corruption rather than repairing it.

After trying to save your data "just in case" you might try using [**`testdisk`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/testdisk.8.html).

You should be able to boot your Live USB and then install testdisk with
`sudo apt-get install testdisk`.

I would suggest starting with `sudo testdisk -l /dev/sda` just to see what it returns. After that perhaps the ["*TestDisk Step By Step*"](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) web page might help?

Comment: Thank you, but firstly i am trying to run chkdsk from windows. In the meantime i was able to get an windows cd.

Comment: @NAlex Your first problem is **NOT** at the file system level and I'm not sure `CHKDSK` will do any good at this point. But it's your data ...

Comment: That was the previous advice I received. Now `CHKDSK` is running for almost an hour, do you think I should stop it?

Comment: @NAlex I don't really know enough to say. I'm somewhat amazed that Windows was happy enough with the current partition table entry to allow `CHKDSK` to run. Which partition are you running it again? `sda3`, your main Windows partition? What type of output is `CHKDSK` producing? Did you boot the Windows DVD to a command prompt?

Comment: I got this screen. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8vpS8.png Then I have chosen Startup Repair. Windows attempted to repair but wasn't successful, restarted and now is saying something like "Attempting repairs... Repairing disk errors. This might take over an hour to complete".

Comment: @NAlex So is `CHKDSK` producing any output? Are the progress indicators changing? Or does it seem to be just hung? If it is making progress but just slow then I suggest you wait for it to finish. It is not good to interrupt if there is a possibility it might be in the process of changing something.

Comment: The progress indicators are moving, but there is no % or something that could show me how much longer is going to take. I don't know what it is doing. The only thing I see is "Attempting repairs... Repairing disk errors. This might take over an hour to complete" and the progress indicators moving.

Comment: @NAlex If it is changing things you probably should not interrupt it. But I really have no way of knowing at this point what is happening. I'm just too removed from the situation.

Comment: I don't think there is any way I can see what it is doing so I think I better wait.

Comment: "omitting empty partition" just means there is a zero-sized entry in the partition table that won't be displayed. (Myself, I have one of those and it's not a problem, at least for Linux. Windows not so sure). One can also take a look at the source code of `util-linux` in `libfdisk/src/dos.c`. The latter seems to indicate that extended partitions of size 0, but with non-zero "system id" (thus not marked inactive) are skipped and the message "omitting empty partition (%zu)" is printed out. The code is not fully commented. (And what about empty primary partitions?)

Answer (score 1):

You have just deleted ubuntu drive without removing mbr.

Fix it following - http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-mbr-xp-vista/

Answer (score 0):

Boot your system with external CD / USB drive which contains Linux (Ubuntu). When the system is ready, plug in the USB drive and copy your required data. Then reboot your system with Windows 7 CD drive. Go to repair, where you will find command prompt. Type 
`/fixmbr`.

This will fix your master boot record for Windows 7. Then login in Windows 7, right click on *My computer* -> `Manage` -> `Disk management`. You will find your Linux partition. Simply remove it from there.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I can't acces my hard disk from my live usb. Do you have any idea how i can acces it?

Comment: In your case '/dev/sda5' is your Linux partition, try to mount it
by '# mount /dev/sda5 /mount/mylinux' 
then try, if it not works then press 'alt + F2' type 'computer' you will find computer icon click on it, it will show what are the drives in your has check whether its showing your Linux partition. Try to open it your Linux partition from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue about restoring your Windows 7 partition has already been answered by Microsoft. There are three commands that you need to invoke after you have inserted the Windows 7 boot disk and started the Repair option. [Here is the link for your consideration.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/when-i-boot-i-get-the-following-msg-error-no-such/6b2a2d89-9e9c-4fcb-89bb-7cad29046fbb)