# I need to uninstall ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu from a Ubuntu LiveCD image to dual boot. I did this on my GFs Windows 7 system and now she wants me to remove it so she can have her Win 7 back, she got tired of the boot options screen. Well, last night I booted to Win 7 and through Disk Management I deleted the contents of the Ubuntu partition and now when i boot the system the screen says GRUB recovery....not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Not an actual duplicate question, bu this may be of use:- http://askubuntu.com/questions/148718/windows-no-longer-boots-on-dual-boot-system?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. reinstall ubuntu
2. change the grub order so that if you do nothing Windos will start as first.
   You can use an easy-to-use the GUI application called Grub Customizer to make your life a little bit easier. As the name suggests, you can do much more than just reordering GRUB menu entries with it.

You can install it by typing the following in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

see [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order). (note change the time out from 10 to 5, so Windows wille start after 5 sec. if you do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

GRUB is the bootloader that Ubuntu installed on your hard disk, replacing the Windows 7 bootloader. It can't run without certain files from your Ubuntu partition, which you deleted. You'll need to reinstall the Windows 7 bootloader. To do this, you'll Windows 7 install media. Instructions are here: ["How to Manually Repair Windows 7 Boot Loader Problems"](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).